# Go Routine: Multiple Consumers to RabbitMQ

Tags: go, rabbitmq

Here I'm trying to create the multiple consumers of rabbitmq queue using the goroutines. Also, I'm trying to achieve a graceful shutdown. Is the following approach create any memory leaks? or is it the correct way to handle them?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
    "syscall"
    "time"

    amqp "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

var notifyClose = make(chan *amqp.Error)

func MaxParallelism() int {
    maxProcs := runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0)
    numCPU := runtime.NumCPU()
    if maxProcs < numCPU {
        return maxProcs
    }
    return numCPU
}

// newConsumer is a function create a rabbitMQ consumer
func newConsumer(connectionString string, fetchCount int) (connection *amqp.Connection, channel *amqp.Channel) {
    connection, _ = amqp.Dial(connectionString)
    channel, _ = connection.Channel()
    channel.Qos(fetchCount, 0, false)

    channel.NotifyClose(notifyClose)
    channel.NotifyPublish(notifyConfirm)
    return
}

func worker(channel *amqp.Channel, done chan bool, queueName, consumerName string) {
    msgs, _ := channel.Consume(
        queueName,    // queue
        consumerName, // consumer
        false,        // auto-ack
        false,        // exclusive
        false,        // no-local
        false,        // no-wait
        nil,          // args
    )

    for m := range msgs {
        body := string(m.Body)
        log.Printf("Processing data %+v\n", body)
        log.Printf("Processing data %+v done\n", body)
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        m.Ack(false)
        log.Printf("Data %+v acked\n", body)
    }
    done <- true
}

func main() {
    defer log.Println("Program stopped successful")
    url := "amqp://user:password@localhost:5672/"
    queue := "my_queue"
    name := "consumer"
    fetchSize := 10

    maxWorkers := MaxParallelism()
    fmt.Println("Maximum workers:", maxWorkers)
    log.Printf("Connecting to %s queue %s fetch-size %d\n", url, queue, fetchSize)
    connection, channel := newConsumer(url, fetchSize)
    log.Printf("Consumer %s is subscribing queue %s\n", name, queue)

    defer connection.Close()
    defer channel.Close()
    defer log.Println("Closing qeueu channel and connection")

    done := make(chan bool, maxWorkers)
    for i := 0; i < maxWorkers; i++ {
        go worker(channel, done, queue, "consumer-"+strconv.Itoa(i))
    }

    exit := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(exit, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    select {
    case <-notifyClose:
        closeWorkes(channel)
    case <-exit:
        closeWorkes(channel)
        log.Println("Got exit signal")
        // Stop recieving message from queue
        log.Println("Stopped receiving message from queue")
        // Wait for worker procrss recieved message
        log.Println("Wait for worker procrss recieved message")
    }
    <-done
    log.Println("Woker done")
    // Just to print if all goroutines are closed or not
    // it is returning 4 and that is correct
    // the main goroutine
    // the background sweeper (the phase of the garbage collection which is concurrent)
    // the scavenger (also part of the garbage collector)
    // the finalizer goroutine (exclusively running the finalizers eventually attached to objects)
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Remaining goroutines", runtime.NumGoroutine())
}

func closeWorkes(channel *amqp.Channel) {
    maxWorkers := MaxParallelism()
    for i := 0; i < maxWorkers; i++ {
        channel.Cancel("consumer-"+strconv.Itoa(i), false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the following approach creating any memory leaks?

Go is a garbage-collected language, which means any allocations are cleaned up by the GC. Unless you're using Cgo and `malloc`-ing memory, you don't really have to worry too much about memory leaks.

---

Since `MaxParallelism` is used within the package, you can rename it `maxParallelism`.

---

```
connection, _ = amqp.Dial(connectionString)
```

You're not checking the error here. In fact, you're not checking errors anywhere. Ignoring errors is not recommended. In fact, using `connection` or `channel` without checking the errors may mean they can be `nil`, which will cause the program to panic when used.

---

I see in `main` that the caller of `newConsumer` has to call `defer connection.Close()` and `defer channel.Close()`. This is fine, I guess, for smaller programs. As programs get more complicated, errors are bound to creep in. What if the caller forgets to close a channel or connection or both? Suggest passing a function to the caller; the caller now has to explicitly ignore the returned value or defer the call to it. For example,

```
func newConsumer(...) (*amqp.Connection, *amqp.Channel, func()) {
    ...
    return connection, channel, func() {
            channel.Close()
            connection.Close()
    }
}

func main() {
     ...
     conn, channel, closeFn := newConsumer(...)
     defer closeFn() 
}
```

---

```
for i := 0; i < maxWorkers; i++ {
        go worker(channel, done, queue, "consumer-"+strconv.Itoa(i))
}
```

Beware of this trap. This might not behave as expected. The goroutine captures the value of the loop variable. By the time the goroutine gets scheduled, the value of `i` may not be the same.

A simple example can be found here: https://go.dev/play/p/HkDLewt-op_U

An easy way to fix this is to capture the variable inside the loop.

```
for i := 0; i < maxWorkers; i++ {
        i := i      // <------ this
        go worker(channel, done, queue, "consumer-"+strconv.Itoa(i))
}
```

Example: https://go.dev/play/p/tWU3KHcYOMk

---

Prefer using `fmt.Sprintf("consumer-%d", i)` over `"consumer-"+strconv.Itoa(i)`

---

In the examples I linked above, you might have seen me using `sync.WaitGroup`. This is the preferred way to 'wait' for goroutines to finish instead of manually creating a channel and sending messages.

If your goroutines may return an error (as they should because of the call to `channel.Consume`, prefer using [`errgroup`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup).

---

Speaking of,

```
<- done
```

will only wait for a single message i.e. will only block until the first goroutine finishes. All the other goroutines may still be doing work.

---

I'm not sure what this line is trying to achieve:

```
// it is returning 4 and that is correct
...
fmt.Println("Remaining goroutines", runtime.NumGoroutine())
```

You should not try to make guesses about how many goroutines are currently active.

---

nit: `closeWorkers`, not `closeWorkes`.

Comment: thank you for the review. I have adjusted the code according to your feedback.

Comment: @Srikanth If your changes are significant enough, you can post a new version of your code as a new question. Feel free to add a link in the new question pointing towards your older question for extra context.

Comment: @Rish, the "capturing loop variable" is good general advice, however, note that it doesn't apply here: when you start a goroutine with `go`, the *arguments* are evaluated first in the calling goroutine, and `strconv.Itoa(i)` produces a new string value each time. Even if you do pass `i` directly as `go worker(i)` it's okay, because `i` is copied into the `worker()` arg each loop. It's only when you capture it in a closure without explicitly passing it that this is a problem.